# Why does this combination of tail and grep freeze my ssh session after a while?

Tags: linux, ssh, freeze, grep

```
sudo tail -f -n0 /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -Ev '1.2.3.4'
```

I have an nginx.log that I need to monitor for all lines except those with my own IP (1.2.3.4). The web server doesn't see much activity besides connections from my own IP so I want to see what else is happening.

The above command combo works for cca. 10 minutes and after that the command output just freezes - my ssh session does not terminate, but it takes a long time to bring it back alive with Ctrl-Z.

Any ideas?

Edit1: I've tried the suggestions posted so far and none of them seem to work beyond what the above command is able to achieve.

Comment: Side note: `.` is a metacharacter in regex, no matter if you use `grep` with or without `-E`. Did you mean `-F`? Most likely this is not relevant to the issue. Still in general such pattern with `-v` can filter out some lines you do want to see, so pay attention.

Comment: I wonder if you have a subtle MTU issue and are generating large bursts if data causing issues?   Tangentially, grep --line-buffered will allow you to read lines as they are logged and might solve your problem, and will likely make debugging easier as you font need to wait for buffers to fill up.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not sure, I think I've found the -Ev in a response to a similar issue here on Super User. Are you saying I should try with -Fv? In any case I'm trying now with the --line-buffered as suggested by davidgo , so will see how that goes.

Comment: I'm saying the `1.2.3.4` *pattern* will match e.g. `1928374` or the beginning of `192.3.48.whatever`.

Comment: Note `grep -vF 1.2.3.4` blocks `11.2.3.44`, you probably want `-w` as well. Again, most likely this is not relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep -v` in a `tail -f` is generally a bad idea. The regular expression in a growing grep is a bad idea too.

You better try something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | perl -pe 'if (/1\.2\.3\.4/) {$_ = ""}'
```

Add `-n0` if you need to follow only new lines.

EDIT: be aware to have the ' outside the $ sign, to avoid shell evaluation

Comment: Any explanation *why* it is a bad idea? I don't claim it's good, bad or whatever. My point is some insight is needed. Without it I read "it is allegedly a bad idea".

Comment: So I've tried the solution given in your answer, i.e.

    tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | perl -pe "if (/123\.12\.123\.123/) {$_ = ''}"

But maybe I'm doing it wrong and I get the error:

> Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "''}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: 1/ It will not release the pipe buffer, so it will grow forever. Furthermore, the grep -v will display an empty line at each removed line from the input.

2/ You’re right! I’ve inverted single and double quotes.
perl -pe 'if (…) {$_ =  ""}' to avoid the $ sign to be interpreted by shell.